# OnCreate bundle is null despite calling onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, bundle, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to restore the previous state of my `Activity` after pressing home and reopening the app so I'm saving what I need inside `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVE_VIEW_ID, mActiveViewId);

        Log.v(TAG, this.toString() + " onSaveInstanceState");

    }
```

that is called, but inside `onCreate` the `Bundle` is always `null`.

This is OnCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle inState) {
    super.onCreate(inState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setMenuDrawer();


    if (inState != null) {

        int activeViewID = inState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVE_VIEW_ID);
        View activeView = findViewById(activeViewID);
        menuDrawer.setActiveView(activeView);
        switchSelectedFragment(activeView);
        Log.v(TAG, this.toString() + " onCreate " + inState.toString());


    } else {
        switchSelectedFragment(findViewById(R.id.homeView));

    }

    Log.v(TAG, this.toString() + " onCreate");

}
```

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState(bundle) and  onSaveInstanceState(bundle) is used to save the state during activity orientation change. Using shared prefrences would help your case.

Comment: so the bundle created inside the onSaveInstanceState call after the home press is not the one read by the following onCreate?

Comment: Your expectations are correct, however a few things can affect this behavior. Do you have any flags set on your `Activity` in the manifest or when it is started? Also, post your `menuDrawer.saveState()` and `onCreate()` methods.

Comment: modified the post with onCreate and remove             outState.putParcelable(STATE_MENUDRAWER, menuDrawer.saveState());
because it is ininfluent

Comment: @Raghunandan will u please help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903545/how-to-call-framelayout-slider-in-diffrent-activties-in-android

Comment: @Raghunandan on this question also i need u r help .please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835135/set-text-on-a-gridview-image-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSaveInstanceState` *is* called when the home button is pressed, but `onCreate` will not be called again unless the Activity was destroyed (config change or memory reasons).

You should simply be able to hold onto the member variable, for dealing with `onPause`/`onResume` (which is what we're actually discussing). If you're not seeing the Fragment you'd expect (after returning from Home press), you have a different issue.

Comment: So how it is possible that pressing the home button and pressing the app icon I see the call of on create?

Comment: @brescia123 That shouldn't happen, and means you are doing something wrong. Perhaps, in onPause?

Comment: It should also be noted, that if you are using Fragments properly, you shouldn't need a transaction to restore the Fragment when the savedInstanceState is not null.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do all the saving work in onPause() method, preferably using sharedPreferences as Raghunandan said.