# Set Text on a GridView Image in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I have a grid view that have 8 images [image: like this]

Now on a particular image view i want to set a text value that will be changed dynamically [image: Like This]

**Main XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Inner XML Layout **

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Code Main Activity**

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, DASHBOARD_LINKS));
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] dashBoardValues;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] dashBoardValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dashBoardValues = dashBoardValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from dashboard_inner.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_inner, null);
            // set image based on selected text
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic);


        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dashBoardValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

So how could i do this in a grid view .Please help me .

Comment: not only your images post your code also.then only we will understand your problem.and help you..

Comment: Check this..https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger , I guess this would be helpfull:)

Comment: i have posted the code also

Comment: Modify your row layout of GridView and add a Textview there.. to get more info/ help add your code.

Comment: I have added all the code please help me now to get this feature ...

Comment: dynamically means text will be set on server value change?

Comment: yes as there will be any request from the server it will be changed .if the req is 1 ,2,3 it will be changed as it is @PiyushGupta

Comment: @PoojaDubey so yu have to store that value in arraylist and set accroding to it to textview

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes u r right with respect to the size of array i have to change the value

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44140/discussion-between-pooja-dubey-and-piyush-gupta)

Comment: @PoojaDubey Is it Completed?

Comment: @PiyushGupta still i haven't got the solution

Comment: @PoojaDubey you have only 8 images always, that means you are trying to create a dashboard ah ?

Comment: @kathir yes u r right and on a single image i want to update the text dynamically

Comment: @PoojaDubey On a single image , is it okay to be the text at bottom of each image. with drawable on top.

Comment: @kathir please see the image for the refrence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already suggested you can use a Relative Layout or FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Check this answer kcoppock which will give you an idea of how to use framelayout

[Placing/Overlapping(z-index) a view above another view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android)

Also it is better to use a `ViewHolder` Pattern

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is actual working code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "AAA";

    private static Handler mHandler;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private GridView mGridView;
    private int click = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());

        click = 0;

        setContentView(R.layout.my_grid_view);
        mGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.my_grid_view);
        mGridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterViews, View pView, int position, long id) {

                click++;
                TextView textView = (TextView)pView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
                if(textView!=null){
                    textView.setText("Changed : Position = " + position + " : Click No = " + click);
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "Fish : textView = " + textView);
                }
            }
        });

    }


    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 200;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView == null){ //This is memory efficient, but after certain no of time u will get similar view repetition, 
                //to over come that overwrite getViewTypeCount() & provide proper way of persistent view & data management mechanism.
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_one, null);
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }}
```

And XMLs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

And

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/flower_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="Default Text" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: which one is child ??Please post the screen shot

Comment: 2nd one is child which one is returned from getView().
1st one is set as setContentView(R.layout.my_grid_view);
Both are two different XML files in "res/layout"

Answer (score 0):

instead of image view pass framelayout reference. it will work. 
    framelayout is view group which sub class of view only.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/badge_view"
    android:text="10"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

snap shot

[image]

Comment: what i have to do in may grid view to get this

Comment: replace *Inner XML Layout * code with my code, and change my image view id to ur id (grid_item_image)

Comment: i am getting this exception now  com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Local path doesn't exist.

Comment: Please modify u r xml

Comment: it is not working for me i need it on a particular image and it is not showing up on the top of my image .can u help me set on ca particular image not on all the images

Comment: i have already posted the xml code that it  and the changes u have i want to change a particular image not on each and every one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44144/discussion-between-sush-and-pooja-dubey)

Answer (score 0):

Get this image and add to your project drawble. [new http://www.flickr.com/photos/113556524@N05/11793569304/](http://www.flickr.com/photos/113556524@N05/11793569304/)

This is the screen shot [nw http://www.flickr.com/photos/113556524@N05/11793569304/](http://www.flickr.com/photos/113556524@N05/11793569304/)

This your xml code to use :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/aaa"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/aaa"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/aaa"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/aaa"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/aaa"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/aaa"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/aaa"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/aaa"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity java file use this :

```
package com.example.dashboard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1,b2,b4,b3,b5,b6,b7,b8;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.neww);

        b1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);




        /* Wat ever you want validation , anything do here */

       // if you need to set text to button 

        b1.setText("Hi pooja");


        //  blah blah blah - wat ever you want to any button text



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Got it ;)

Comment: so how could i set the text on the top of the images as i have in the question

Comment: delete background="@null" and instead of drawbleontop, just use drawwble.

Comment: Please attach the screen shot it is missing

Comment: see these links , uploadins scren shots r prblms

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44587/discussion-between-pooja-dubey-and-kathir)

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout as child of GridView. Within FrameLayout first put ImageView & on top of it put a TextView as mentioned by "sush".
Then you can change Visibility & content of TextView on demand, through program.
It is not working for you because probably for all TextViews of you have put same "android:id" put different id for different TextView. It is bound to work. I've tested.

Comment: Sorry, for that u have to wait till evening, as in my office, copy & paste to out side office LAN is not allowed here :(

Comment: ok fine i waiting for u r reply .as i need to put a text on a particular image .and the text will be dynamically added .Point to note on a single image i want to put the text

Answer (score 0):

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUY4o.png Check the sample image...
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/album_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cover"
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="148dp"
    android:src="@drawable/empty_photo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cover"
    android:background="#70000000"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---> Use this layout and inflate it in your adapter.You will get the text at bottom of image.

Comment: i want the text on the top of the image at right side as in the question

Comment: Instead of alignBottom in linearlayout use alignTop...it will work

Comment: I have to show 8 images in one of them i have to put the text on the top dynamically .so can u post the complete code how could i get this please

Comment: In your adapter use position variable to set text at particular position and in remaining positions set text as null or dont set any text.

Comment: will u see the images as i have posted in the question do u feel that u r code will help me to get that