# adding TextView and ImageView in gridAdapter error : text not appearing

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, universal-image-loader

My gridView adapter is fine until recently i decided to add a TextView together with ImageView. My images some appearing some not appearing and my TextViews completely not appearing. My whole gridView now is a disaster D: I've no idea how. I've searched everywhere. I tried but I still can't D:

I tried :

[UIL- tutorial adding TextView and ImageView](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-the-universal-image-loader-library-to-handle-your-images.html)
<- doesn't work

[custom GridView with ImageView and TextView](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html) <- doesn't work

Here's my code :

```
public class MyGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> imageNames = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
private Resources resources;

public MyGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> images, ArrayList<String> imageNames)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
    this.imageNames = imageNames;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private static class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder currentViewholder;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    LinearLayout outerLayout;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //recycling logic
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_images, null);

    }

    currentViewholder = new ViewHolder();
    currentViewholder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivGrid_images);
    currentViewholder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGrid_images);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imageLoader.displayImage("drawable://" + images.get(position),currentViewholder.imageView);
    currentViewholder.textView.setText(imageNames.get(position));
    Log.d("TextView", imageNames.get(position));
    Log.d("TextView" , String.valueOf(images.get(position)));
    return convertView;

}

}
```

Did I do anything wrong? Please help :< It worked perfectly fine before i added the TextView :<

Comment: Use `ViewHolder` in getView method to get it work correctly

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i tried.. like the link i've mentioned.. but still can't work..

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no wait what do you mean use in getView? it's inside getView isn't :O you meant inside the if(convertView == null) isit? if yes ,i tried.. if no, please tell me how to use in getView D:

Comment: Ok, please show code with `ViewHolder` which u have tried

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK that's the ViewHolder code D:

Answer (score 0):

I've SOLVED THIS!! It's behaving weird because it's overlapping!

Thanks to this two links I kept thinking what's wrong. Then I tried putting my LinearLayout orientation. Then it worked!

1. [Set Text on a GridView Image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835135/set-text-on-a-gridview-image-in-android)
2. [Placing/Overlapping(z-index) a view above another view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android)